# Find, move, replace and parse strings simultanuosly while building an .xml playlist file

Tags: replace, playlist

I get many videos and I need to compile functioning .xml playlist files where they are all listed, including snapshot jpg's. Videos and snapshot images are named automatically. So I end up with lots of files like this:

hxxp://site.com/video/_5712.480p.flv

hxxp://site.com/video/_5712.480p.jpg

hxxp://site.com/video/_5713.480p.flv

hxxp://site.com/video/_5713.480p.jpg

So with these files I need to produce an .xml file looking something like this:

`....`

```
    <track>
        <title>5712.480p</title>
        <creator>Whatever_5712.480p</creator>
        <info>hxxp://site.com/video/_5712.480p.jpg</info>
        <annotation>Playlist marked_480p</annotation>
        <location>hxxp://site.com/video/_5712.480p.flv</location>
        <image>hxxp://site.com/video/_5712.480p.jpg</image>

    </track>
    <track>
        <title>5713.480p</title>
        <creator>Whatever_5713.480p</creator>
        <info>hxxp://site.com/video/_5713.480p.jpg</info>
        <annotation>Playlist marked_480p</annotation>
        <location>hxxp://site.com/video/_5713.480p.flv</location>
        <image>hxxp://site.com/video/_5713.480p.jpg</image>

    </track>
```

So I guess I might be looking at some advanced sed/awk procedure to copy, move and place the right strings inside the correct brackets, and to compile one whole file? I really appreciate all the help I can get on this one. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that input, you can do something like:

```
awk 'NR%2==1 && /\.jpg$/ {JPGFILE=$0}
     NR%2==0 { print "whateverXMLtags" JPGFILE "whatanotherXMLtags" $0 "someotherXMLtags" }' INPUTFILELIST
```

So this assumes that `jpg` files are on odd numbered lines, and on that saves the name, and on every even line prints the desired output. *Note* that the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> between e.g. `JPGFILE` and `"whatanotherXMLtags"` concatenates the sring.

Comment: Aah. Thanks a lot! That really made my day! Works splendidly, and I added line brakes easily like so:

{ print "\n<track>" "\n   <title>"  JPGFILE.....

probably not the nicest way to do it, but it works. Thanks again!